# how to extract nouns and substantives from a phrase?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I would like to extract nouns, substantives and adjectives from a given text phrase. Is there a java library (open source) that does that? Does anyone know how to do that?

Basically, I was thinking in creating separated dictionaries for these categories (nouns, substantives, adjectives) and then parse the phrase, separate words in tokens and compare against these dictionaries but having something (lib) that already does that for me would be great. More perfect if it supports Brazilian Portuguese language!

Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but generally speaking questions about specific libraries or requests for good libraries are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. That said, consider looking into the Stanford NLP package, which is often used to do this. Alternatively, look at Parsey McParseface.

Comment: "Noun" and "substantive" are the same part of speech category. Anyway, questions about locating libraries etc are expressly discouraged on Stack Overflow. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

[Opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html) is a good java library to achieve what you want.

have a look at this [blog](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-tutorial.html) for setup, and this [blog](http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.in/2013/05/search-noun-adjectives-verbs-from-text.html) clearly explains how to extract nouns,adjectives and verbs.

hope this helps!